# AES256 encryption get different result between node.js and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, encryption, aes

1.Node.js

```
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var key = "my password";
    var text = "text to encrypt";  
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc',key);  
    var crypted =cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64');
    crypted+=cipher.final('base64');
```

Result: *ZeYCYOrR/w7qSAZVYht8+Q==*

2.Objective-C

```
{
    NSString *key = @"my password";
    NSString *text = @"text to encrypt";
    NSData *plain = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *cipher = [plain AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", [cipher base64Encoding] );
}
```

Result: *raFGdTWYvSPWpkgtF9LJIg==*

`[AES256EncryptWithKey:]` is  *[HERE](https://gist.github.com/Veelian/7541502)*

Comment: My guess is that node.js is auto-generating an IV value, while iOS is using an all-zero vector.  Try specifying the same IV value for both (The docs indicate there is a node.js method that will accept an IV as well).

Comment: @borrrden there is a mehtod `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`,how should I set iv?

Comment: It is just any 128-bit long binary string, you can choose whatever you want, you just need to use the same one on both sides.

Comment: Actually I think you need to convert the string in node.js to binary first like you do in the Objective-C version, but I am not sure how (unfamiliar with node).

Comment: I have different result by executing your node.js code. Is this result from using given key and given text or is it result from your production code?

Comment: @tomekK key and text is here: `var key = "my password";
    var text = "text to encrypt";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that node.js `crypto.createCipher` internally uses a key derivation  function `EVP_BytesToKey()` to generate the AES key and iv from the `key = "my password"`. Thus the actual AES keys are different for node.js and Common Crypto.

The answer is to use `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)` in place of `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)`.

From the node.js documentation:

> In line with OpenSSL's recommendation to use pbkdf2 instead of EVP_BytesToKey it is recommended you derive a key and iv yourself with crypto.pbkdf2 and to then use createCipheriv() to create the cipher stream.